# Converting retrieved datetime from database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to send the date to my Android device in JSON format. Also, the time is in 24 hours format. How can I change this into 12 hours format?

PHP

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * from news Order by n_date Desc";
$con = mysqli_connect($server_name, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass, $db_name);

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$response = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    array_push($response, array("title" => $row[2], "content" => $row[3], "n_date" => $row[4]));
}

echo json_encode(array("news_response" => $response));

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

The JSON response:

```
{"news_response":[{"title":"news","content":"content","n_date":"2016-11-12 10:47:23"}]}
```

I am trying to convert the `2016-11-12` to something like `November 12, 2016 10:47:23`. How do I do this?

I couldn't find any example online.

Comment: Use DateTime http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in PHP:

```
echo (new DateTime('2016-11-12 10:47:23'))->format('F d, y GA:i:s');
```

in MySQL:

```
SELECT concat(MONTHNAME(date),' ', DAY(date), ' ', TIME(date)) from news;
```

Comment: But i am trying to get data from mysql. Example if i have many data. Should i do it one by one?

Comment: you received your data from mysql, as '2016-11-12 10:47:23' so push in your result array transformed value.

Comment: How to do it sir?

Comment: array_push($response, array("title"=>$row[2],"content"=>$row[3], "n_date"=>(new DateTime($row[4]))->format('F d, y GA:i:s')));

or you doing it elsewhere? also I've updated aswer where you just can update sql

Answer (score 1):

you can use `echo date('F j, Y H:i:s',strtotime('2016-11-12 10:47:23'));`

Comment: But i am trying to get data from mysql. Example if i have many data. Should i do it one by one?

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP's [date_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

```
$date = date_create("2016-11-12 10:47:23");
echo date_format($date, 'g:ia \o\n l jS F Y');
```

Comment: But i am trying to get data from mysql. Example if i have many data. Should i do it one by one?

Comment: That's one way, another one is to use DATE_FORMAT(date,'%d/%m/%Y') in your sql query.

Comment: so in the select query, i should convert the dattime already?

Comment: Yes, You can do that.

Comment: How to do it sir? can you provide some codes sir? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
echo date('M d,Y H:i:s', strtotime('2016-11-12 10:47:23'));
```